# как убрать скачек экрана вверх при клике на ссылку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой кусок кода. Это табы, и при клике по переключателю страничка подпрыгивает, я допер почему она подпрыгивает, из-за значка **#**, так вот вопрос к знатокам, как это действие (подпрыгивание) убрать. А то на мобильной версии вообще жесть происходит

```js
$(function() {
  var t = 1;

  function switchTabs() {
    if (t > 3) t = 1;
    console.log("switchTabs - ", t);
    if (t == 1) $('a.my-tab[href="#tabs-1"]').click();
    if (t == 2) $('a.my-tab[href="#tabs-2"]').click();
    if (t == 3) $('a.my-tab[href="#tabs-3"]').click();
    t++;
  }
  var sw_tabs_timer1 = window.setInterval(switchTabs, 1000);

  $('a.my-tab').click(function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.isTrusted && sw_tabs_timer1) {
      sw_tabs_timer1 = clearInterval(sw_tabs_timer1);
      console.log("stopped switchTabs");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabNavigation">
    <li><a class="my-tab" href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="my-tab" href="#tabs-2">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="my-tab" href="#tabs-3">3</a></li>    
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    img
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    img
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    img
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем Вы изуродовали "Фрагмент кода"?

Comment: @Igor, ковырялся в редакторе кода, и так и так пробовал, не получается решить вопрос, на этом примере то все происходит как надо. Не могу найти решение этого вопроса

Comment: Вы перенесли `e.preventDefault();` внутрь `if`?

Comment: $('a.my-tab').click(function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.isTrusted && e.preventDefault && sw_tabs_timer1) {
      sw_tabs_timer1 = clearInterval(sw_tabs_timer1);
      console.log("stopped switchTabs");
    }
  });

Comment: Вот так поставил, в консоли се работает, сейчас попробую на сайт перенести и проверить

Comment: Минуточку, это какая-то ерунда.

Comment: В консоле работает, а на экране не работает, так и скачет

Comment: У меня в ответе совсем не такой код, как в Вашем комментарии.

Comment: Так я Вам отвечал на него, что после внедрения кода Вашего ответа, перестали автоматически переключаться табы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемму скачков решил, не потеряв изначально задвнных параметров по автоматичскому переключению табов. Прописал действие onclick="return false;" непосредственно в код HTML

```html
<li><a class="my-tab" onclick="return false;" href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
```

Comment: только табы теперь не переключаются.. <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: null --> <!-- language: lang-html --> <li><a class="my-tab" onclick="return false;" href="#tabs-1">1</a></li> <!-- end snippet -->

Answer (score 0):

Строка с `// !!!` в скрипте:

```js
$(function() {
  var t = 1;

  function switchTabs() {
    if (t > 3) t = 1;
    //console.log("switchTabs - ", t);
    if (t == 1) $('a.my-tab[href="#tabs-1"]').click();
    if (t == 2) $('a.my-tab[href="#tabs-2"]').click();
    if (t == 3) $('a.my-tab[href="#tabs-3"]').click();
    t++;
  }
  var sw_tabs_timer1 = window.setInterval(switchTabs, 1000);

  $('a.my-tab').click(function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.isTrusted) {
      e.preventDefault(); // !!!
      if (sw_tabs_timer1) {
        sw_tabs_timer1 = clearInterval(sw_tabs_timer1);
        //console.log("stopped switchTabs");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  border:1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabNavigation">
    <li><a class="my-tab" href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="my-tab" href="#tabs-2">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="my-tab" href="#tabs-3">3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>

  <div id="tabs-1">
    img
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    img
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    img
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Перестал автоматически переключать табы, а так же перестал скакать экран))

Comment: каким образом оставить автоматическое перелистывание и убрать этот самый скачок? Ваш вариант решил проблему скачка, но убрал работу переключения табов

Comment: @ИгорьЛебедев Постарайтесь добавить в вопрос код, чтобы создать работающий пример.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); // !!! вы порекомендовали добавить это действие в функцию, при этом работа автоматического переключения табов прекратилась. Вот здесь вы давали мне совет, каким образом остановить переключение табов при клике https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/1475751?noredirect=1